# Server Migrations

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain

We are looking to relocate our office location to other location.
Right now we have TWO 2008R2 servers. One is PDC & second is ADC.

During office relocation process we can't shift everyone in one shot.
That will be 50-50 transition.

So My question is can I relocate my ADC 1st to the new office location. 50% clients along with that server.
Then renaming clients may shift in next 5-10 days along with my PDC.

Both of this server's hold below roles.
AD, DNS, IIS, MS SQL, File servers.

Will this affect any of the functionality to either of the location for up to 10 days.

Thanks,
Sandesh

Answer (score 0):

All of the problems stambata identified are possible.

One solution you can consider, is having configuring a site to site VPN from your new location to your old location and leaving the servers in your old location.

When everyone is moved over, move your servers and remove the site to site VPN.